# Why does Git rebase in Visual Studio 2019 Team Explorer report a merge conflict for changes to lines that are far apart?

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-merge, rebase, git-merge-conflict

I have a branch that made a change at line 189 and a branch that made a change at line 258. Visual Studio Team Explorer is reporting a conflict. The 1-line changes from Source branch and Target branch, respectively, are shown below.

[image of 1-line change to Source branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSkCU.png)

[image of 1-line change to Target branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfdWT.png)

Comment: What does the conflict look like?

Comment: If you copy and paste the lines of code, and format them appropriately, you make easier for everybody to help you.

Comment: @eftshift0 The linked images show a source branch change and a target branch change to the same file, about 70 lines apart. Visual Studio rebase reports this as a conflict to resolve, rather than making both changes, as Git merge ordinarily would.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I couldn't think of a way to show in a code snippet what each branch's file change is so I used images, not realizing that the images would show up as links since I have less than 10 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

VS is detecting those as deletes from the opposite file respectively. Because each has a change that it is detecting as a delete it doesn't know which one to take.

Comment: Ordinarily Git merge would accept both changes in a case like this where the two changes are far apart in the file. My question is why this is not the case when using rebase in Visual Studio 2019. I did find [link](https://saraford.net/2017/04/25/how-to-resolve-a-conflict-during-a-rebase-in-visual-studio-115/) helpful in quickly accepting both changes.

Comment: I'd say it's Microsoft stuff and that's a BIG black box.